# how to get value of drop down in same php page with mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selectstate').change(function() {
window.location = "dropexmpl.php?stateval=" + $(this).val();
});
$('#selectcity').change(function() {
        window.location = "dropexmpl.php?cityval=" + $(this).val();
    });
});
</div>
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div>
<?php
//state drop down
    echo "<td"." id="."id_sel_state".">";
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("data_filter",$con);
    $query=("SELECT id,state_name FROM state_details ");
    $result = mysql_query ($query); 
    echo "<label id='statelab'>Select state : </label>"."<select name='filterstate'id='selectstate' onchange='getstateval()'>";

    while ($nt = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value='".$nt['id']."'>".$nt['state_name']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
//city drop down
    $statestrval= $_GET['stateval'];
    echo "<td id='id_sel_city'>";
    $query1="SELECT id,state_id,city_name FROM city_details WHERE state_id=".$statestrval."";                                                                               $result1 = mysql_query ($query1);
    echo "<label>Select city : </label>"."<select name='filtercity' id='selectcity' >";
    while ($nt = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    echo "<option value='".$nt['id']."'>".$nt['city_name']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

//Zone drop down

    $citystrval= $_GET['cityval'];
    echo "<td id="."id_sel_zone".">";
    $query2="SELECT id,city_id,zone_area FROM zone_details WHERE city_id=".$citystrval."";                          

    $result2 = mysql_query ($query2);
    echo "<label>Select industry zone : </label>"."<select name='filterzone' id='selectzone'>";
    while ($nt = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    echo "<option value='".$nt['id']."'>".$nt['zone_area']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    mysql_close($con);
?>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here i used 3 drop down state city and zone.it works but when page is reloaded with window.location code it show me the page with refresh effect how it solve by using ajax.
it should be like when i select the state is should be shows city list related to that state.when city is selected it should be shows the zone related to that city .but problem is when i go to select the city it change the state list and when i select zone it change the city list because of reloading of page how i can solve this problem.

Comment: I don't understand your problem...

Comment: how i can apply ajax code to get the selected value of the dropdown in this same page.

Comment: where is ajax code in the code posted?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$('#selectstate').change(function() {
window.location = "dropexmpl.php?stateval=" + $(this).val();
});
$('#selectcity').change(function() {
        window.location = "dropexmpl.php?cityval=" + $(this).val();
    });
});

Comment: see in change event of #selectstate and #selectcity i use window.location with selected values of #selectstate and #selectcity. so now how can i pass selected value of #selectstate and #selectcity in same page using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use AJAX, jQuery and avoid page refreshing.
Have a look to the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/